# NodeMCU ESP8266 Socket Takes Time To Make Connection With Python

Tags: sockets, delay, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using NodeMCU ESP8266 on an RC bot to connect to python and give command to run it. The command is stored in dictionary and is to be sent over socket connection. The code is written such that connection is created at begining and breaked at the end of every iteration. The connection of socket takes too long some time which makes the RC bot runs out of boundary. I want to know that is it possible to remove that delay?

Here is the corrosponding python code.

```
    global dictionary

    ports = [1235, 1236, 1237, 1238]
    s = []
    for i in range(4):
        s.append(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
        s[i].bind(('0.0.0.0', ports[i]))
        s[i].listen(0)
    index = 0
    while True:
        then = time.time()

        client, addr = s[index].accept()
        client.settimeout(10)
        y = dictionary
        print(y)
        client.send(bytes(y['func'], encoding='utf8'))
        index = y['l']
        client.close()

        now = time.time()
        print(now - then)
```

Here is the corrosponding NodeMCU ESP8266 code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const uint16_t port = 1234;
const char *host = "10.42.0.1";
WiFiClient client;

int m = 0;
int _m = 2;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(m, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(_m, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(m, LOW);
    digitalWrite(_m, LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Connecting...\n");
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin("Anthrax-Inspiron-5580", "x8XDXYnq"); 
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print("  .");
    }
    Serial.println("Wifi Connected !!");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
    if (!client.connect(host, port))
    {
        Serial.println("Connection to host failed");
        delay(100);
        return;
    }

    delay(250);
    while (client.available() > 0)
    {
        char c = client.read();
        if(c == 'H')
        {
          Serial.println(c);
          digitalWrite(_m, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(m, LOW);
          delay(7000);                   
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.println(c);
          digitalWrite(m, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(_m, LOW);
          delay(7000); 
        }
    }
    client.stop();
}
```

[Click here to see how delay comes in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pryCy.jpg)

Please help me get out of it..

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why are you closing the TCP connection each time through the loop()?

Comment: I am a very beginner in this.. Please guide me to some source or so for both nodemcu esp8266 and pyhton

Comment: There's a ton of resources out there that you can find with Google. My question is, why are you opening and closing the connection each time through `loop()`? Why not just keep it open and reuse it, especially when you're saying it takes too long this way?